# Not able to add more than 1 post request in the mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am using mongo db to fetch and post the data but unable to post more than 1 request here is my code ON posting the different values second time i am getting the error I am unable to find the issue as i am using different values to post but still getting the same error

the very first portion of code. the error:

```
"driver": true,
"name": "MongoError",
"index": 0,
"code": 11000,
"keyPattern": {
    "id": 1
},
"keyValue": {
    "id": null
}
```

```
const express = require('express')
const app=express();
const cors=require('cors')
const mongoose=require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test1',{useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useCreateIndex: true}).then(()=>{console.log("connected")}).catch(err=>console.log(err));
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const userroute=require('./routes/user')

app.use('/user',userroute);

app.listen(8000,()=>console.log("running on 8000"));

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userschema=new mongoose.Schema({
   
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:false
    },
    img:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:false
    },
    summary:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:false
    }
})
module.exports=mongoose.model("User",userschema)

const express=require('express')
const User = require('../model/User.model')
const router=express.Router()

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    User.find().then(users=>res.json(users)).catch(err=>res.json(err))
})
module.exports= router;  

router.post('/add',(req,res)=>{
    const name=req.body.name;
    const img=req.body.img;
    const summary=req.body.summary;
    const details = new User({name,img,summary});
    details.save().then(()=>res.json(" added ")).catch(err=>res.json(err))
})
router.delete('/:id',(req,res)=>{
    User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id).
    then(()=>res.send("deleted")).catch((err)=>res.send(err));
})
```

Comment: can you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: the very first portion of cosde is the error

Comment: "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "id": null
    }
}

Comment: error code 11000, means you are trying to insert duplicate _id field, your mongoose schema looks correct, not sure why mongoose is not creating unique _id automatically every time, what version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: i am using "mongoose": "^5.10.0"

Comment: I am not sure why mongoose is not creating ids, but we can manually create one, adding in answer to write code pls check

Answer (score 0):

Adding in answer to write code, in the comment section it becomes messy to understand the code.

```
router.post('/add',(req,res)=>{
    const name=req.body.name;
    const img=req.body.img;
    const summary=req.body.summary;
    const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    const details = new User({_id, name, img, summary});
    details.save().then(()=>res.json(" added ")).catch(err=>res.json(err))
})
```

Ideally, mongoose should create _id automatically, but we can also create custom ids

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, what I did to solve it was download the latest version of mongodb, https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community, update the path in the environment variables with the new version, download the latest version of mongo shell, finally restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, just simply delete the collection from database and then make a new post request

Answer (score 0):

[Damusan's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498359/not-able-to-add-more-than-1-post-request-in-the-mongo-db/68673973#68673973) worked for me. This problem was insane because everyone who cloned my repo to help me had zero problems, so I knew it was on my end. The user collection accepted one user, then stopped and did exactly as described! The following fixed the problem:

1. *OPEN THE MONGODB SHELL*

   ```
   mongo
   ```
2. *MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THE RIGHT DB NAME=COMMAND TO LIST ALL DATABASES*

   ```
   show dbs
   ```
3. *SWITCH TO THE DATABASE*

   ```
   use <name_of_your_db>
   ```
4. *GET A LIST OF ALL YOUR COLLECTIONS TO CONFIRM USERS IS THERE*

   ```
   show collections
   ```
5. *LIST ALL THE DATA IN THE USERS COLLECTION- IT SHOULD BE JUST ONE USER*

   ```
   db.users.find()
   ```
6. *DROP THE COLLECTION -NO WORRIES, WHEN YOU MAKE A POST AGAIN IT WILL RE-CREATE THE USER COLLECTION*

   ```
   db.users.drop()
   ```
7. *TRY TO LIST THE DATA AGAIN - IT SHOULD BE UNRESPONSIVE*

   ```
   db.users.find()
   ```
8. *LIST YOUR COLLECTIONS AGAIN- IT SHOULD SHOW NO USERS COLLECTION*

   ```
   show collections
   ```
9. *EXIT THE SHELL*

   ```
   exit
   ```

That's it, start the server and make a post for a user in Insomnia, and it should work, **more than once**!